# Location of iTunes/Xcode 4 icons?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, xcode4

I've been looking for the Play icon shared by iTunes and Xcode, plus others and can't find them. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329442/location-of-xcode-icons) reply seems to apply to Xcode 3 but not Xcode 4.

Answer (score 3):

The image resources are located within private frameworks inside the following folder:

/Xcode4/Library/PrivateFrameworks/

(Note, your path may differ if you chose to install Xcode 4 at the default location, /Developer/).

`IDEKit.framework` seems to have most of the new UI-related images in vector (PDF) form. There's also `XDInterface.framework` and `DevToolsInterface.framework`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact location, it's not in the Resources folder.

If you only need the play button, use NSToolbar and NSToolbarItem with this PNG.

[image]